# How do I make a stage in Azure Pipelines depend on the success of anyone of two previous stages?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a stage in my pipeline that needs to wait for the successful conclusion of any of 2 previous stages, which are mutually exclusive. I can use multiple stages in the `dependsOn` property but then the dependent stage will depend on the successful conclusion of all the refered stages, not any single one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like as this:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  . . .

- stage: B
  . . .

- stage: C
  dependsOn:
  - A
  - B
  condition: or(succeeded('A'), succeeded('B'))
```

With this way, the **`stage C`** will run only when **`stage A`** and **`stage B`** completed and any of them is **`succeeded`**.

To view more details, you can see:

- [**Add stages, dependencies, & conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions)
- [**Expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#or)

**[UPDATE]**

For your first question:

> With you solution, would stage C run if either stage A or stage B never finished?

Sure. Stage C will run as long as one of stage A and stage B is completed successfully.

For you second question:

> how to mark the other stage so that the pipeline as a whole is seem as finished after stage C completes.

You mentioned stage A and stage B are mutually exclusive. So, if stage A is executed, stage B should not be executed. Vice versa. So the not executed stage should be marked as **`Skipped`**.

See below pipeline example:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: stage
  displayName: 'Select stage A or B'
  type: string
  default: A
  values:
  - A
  - B

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.stage }}', 'A')
  . . .

- stage: B
  displayName: 'Stage B'
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.stage }}', 'B')
  . . .

- stage: C
  displayName: 'Stage C'
  dependsOn:
  - A
  - B
  condition: or(succeeded('A'), succeeded('B'))
  . . .
```

- When setting the value of the parameter '**`stage`**' as '**`A`**', the condition '**`eq('${{ parameters.stage }}', 'A')`**' is true, stage A is executed. Stage B is not executed and is marked as **`Skipped`**. Stage C is executed after stage A is completed successfully. The whole pipeline run will be marked as **`succeeded`** if stage A and stage C are completed successfully.

  [image]
- When setting the value of the parameter '**`stage`**' as '**`B`**', the condition '**`eq('${{ parameters.stage }}', 'B')`**' is true, stage A is not executed and is marked as **`Skipped`**. Stage B is executed. Stage C is executed after stage B is completed successfully. The whole pipeline run will be marked as **`succeeded`** if stage B and stage C are completed successfully.

  [image]

Comment: As I said, my two stages are mutually exclusive. With you solution, would stage C run if either stage A or stage B never finished? Also, that brings up another issue: how to mark the other stage so that the pipeline as a whole is seem as finished after stage C completes.

Comment: Hi @lpacheco, I have updated mu above answer with more details. Please check it.